# How can I write a macOS program that (when activated) makes it possible to scroll with one finger?

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility, multi-touch, trackpad

How can I write a macOS program that (when activated) makes it possible to scroll with one finger? I believe this should be possible, considering the app [Inklet](https://tenonedesign.com/inklet.php) already makes a much more sophisticated use of the trackpad.

Postscript: To anyone who reads this, please always have customizability in mind when creating programs and interfaces; People with disabilities, like myself, suffer a lot because of arbitrary UI choices that can easily be altered to suit their body.

Comment: Related: [One finger scrolling on a Macbook touchpad](https://superuser.com/questions/666035/one-finger-scrolling-on-a-macbook-touchpad)